# Just stuck with this problem. Having little difficulty in java IO

Tags: java, java-io

Question: "Write a program in java to write 5 email addresses into a file. Now open the same file to read and convert the @ symbol in the email address to # symbol."

I written a code for only one input but how to take input dynamically and change @ with # is showing error. The code below for static input. Please can anyone guide me about the solution for the required question?

```
import java.io.*;
public class Pro3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    int i;
    String sc="Kaushik123@gmail.com";
    FileWriter ob=new FileWriter("idk.txt");
    for(i=0;i<sc.length();i++) {

        ob.write(sc.charAt(i));

    }
    for(i=0;i<sc.length();i++) {

        String r=sc.replace("@","#");

        ob.write( r.charAt( i));

    }
    ob.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Why is `javascript` a tag for a solely `java` based question? Also use proper formatting enclosing your code in between two ```.

Comment: What is the error you receive?  Paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pro3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileWriter ob = new FileWriter("idk.txt");
        String[5] emails = new String[5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
             System.out.println((i + 1) + ". email");
             String email = scan.nextLine();
             emails[i] = email;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < emails[i].length(); j++){
                ob.write(emails[i].charAt(j));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < emails[i].length(); j++){
                String r = emails[i].replace("@","#");
                ob.write( r.charAt(j));
            }
        }

        ob.close();
    }
}
```

Just run your programm for all the mail-addresses i.e. nested for loops

Comment: You will probably need to write new line-characters after every email-write. So (in my post) after code lines 13 and 20.

Comment: can you tell me that what is this loop for j is used?

Comment: There are two loops now. They are **nested**. `i` loops through alle the email address-strings, and `j` loops through the individual characters of an email-string.

Comment: I accidentally introduced your uncertainty by using `i` for something else, as you have. `j` is now performing, what `i` was in your code.

Comment: But the question asked for taking emails dynamically. I mean through console and then write it in a file and after that do the required operations.

Comment: If this is what you wanted, then please consider accepting my answer, by clicking on the check mark!